# Find count of combination in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I want to find the count of combination of values in two columns using HIVE

Input table:

---

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| Col1         |     Col2           |
+--------------+--------------------+
|  Sam         |     Ricky          |
|  Patel       |     Trump          |
|  Suzane      |     Robert         |
|  Ricky       |     Sam            |
|  Bob         |     Ricky          |
|  Robert      |     Suzane         |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

---

Pattern combination found:

```
.............................
|   Sam      |      Ricky   |
|   Ricky    |      Sam     |
|   Suzane   |      Robert  |
|   Robert   |      Suzane  |
.............................
```

Expected Output :

```
  Sam     Ricky  2
  Robert  Suzane 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      least    (col1, col2)   as least_col
           ,greatest (col1, col2)   as greatest_col
           ,count    (*)

from        mytable

group by    least    (col1, col2)
           ,greatest (col1, col2)

having     count (*) >= 2
;
```

#### Demo

```
create table mytable (Col1 string,Col2 string);

insert into mytable values 
    ('Sam'    ,'Ricky' )
   ,('Patel'  ,'Trump' )
   ,('Suzane' ,'Robert')
   ,('Ricky'  ,'Sam'   )
   ,('Bob'    ,'Ricky' )
   ,('Robert' ,'Suzane')
;
```

---

```
select * from mytable;
```

---

```
+--------------+--------------+
| mytable.col1 | mytable.col2 |
+--------------+--------------+
| Sam          | Ricky        |
| Patel        | Trump        |
| Suzane       | Robert       |
| Ricky        | Sam          |
| Bob          | Ricky        |
| Robert       | Suzane       |
+--------------+--------------+
```

---

```
select      col1
           ,col2
           ,least    (col1, col2)   as least_col
           ,greatest (col1, col2)   as greatest_col

from        mytable
;
```

---

```
+--------+--------+-----------+--------------+
|  col1  |  col2  | least_col | greatest_col |
+--------+--------+-----------+--------------+
| Sam    | Ricky  | Ricky     | Sam          |
| Patel  | Trump  | Patel     | Trump        |
| Suzane | Robert | Robert    | Suzane       |
| Ricky  | Sam    | Ricky     | Sam          |
| Bob    | Ricky  | Bob       | Ricky        |
| Robert | Suzane | Robert    | Suzane       |
+--------+--------+-----------+--------------+
```

---

```
select      least    (col1, col2)   as least_col
           ,greatest (col1, col2)   as greatest_col
           ,count    (*)

from        mytable

group by    least    (col1, col2)
           ,greatest (col1, col2)

having     count (*) >= 2
;
```

---

```
+-----------+--------------+-----+
| least_col | greatest_col | _c2 |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
| Robert    | Suzane       |   2 |
| Ricky     | Sam          |   2 |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain the logic behind this also. This would help in tackling bigger problems.  @dudu

Comment: oops!! it was by mistake.Accepted!